# median in SQLITE on group

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following problem: I need the median in sqlite for groups.

Example: I have a network with multiple start and end points and several travel distances between each of them. I now need the median of each start/end pair.

For the following table:

```
    Start  | End  | Time
      A    |  B   |  5
      A    |  B   |  9
      A    |  B   |  6
      B    |  C   |  4
      B    |  C   |  8
      C    |  A   |  5
      C    |  B   |  6
```

I would like the following result:

```
    Start | End  | Median(Time)
      A   |  B   |   6
      B   |  C   |   6
      C   |  A   |   5
      C   |  B   |   6
```

I have seen how to compute the median here: [How can I calculate the median of values in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763965/how-can-i-calculate-the-median-of-values-in-sqlite), but I have no clue how to apply this on groups.

To create the table use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE "Times" ("Key" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "START" TEXT, "END" TEXT, "TIME" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(1,'A','B',5);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(2,'A','B',9);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(3,'A','B',6);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(4,'B','C',4);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(5,'B','C',8);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(6,'C','A',5);
INSERT INTO "Times" VALUES(7,'C','B',6);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add `WHERE` clauses after every `FROM ...`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it work (seams you have can't access outer nested tables from within `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`), but a got this answer:

```
SELECT Start, End, AVG(Time) FROM (
    SELECT *, (
        SELECT COUNT() FROM Times AS _ 
        WHERE Start=Times.Start AND End=Times.End AND (Time>Times.Time OR Time=Times.Time AND ROWID>Times.ROWID)
    )-(
        SELECT COUNT() FROM Times AS _ 
        WHERE Start=Times.Start AND End=Times.End AND (Time<Times.Time OR Time=Times.Time AND ROWID<Times.ROWID)
    ) AS m FROM Times WHERE m BETWEEN -1 AND 1
) GROUP BY Start, End;
```