# SQLite - using subquery with LIMIT and error "table not found"

Tags: sql, sqlite, median

I am trying to calculate the median for a time difference between 2 columns. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763965/how-can-i-calculate-the-median-of-values-in-sqlite) 
BUT, when I incorporate it into my code, I get this error:

> no such table: medianVal: SELECT timeToPost.

EX. of inner table (Users up):

```
id      userJoinDate    firstPost       timeToPost
---------------------------------------------------
3666    1/4/2015 10:48  1/4/2015 11:48    0.04
3669    1/13/2015 8:05  1/13/2015 9:05    0.04
3672    1/13/2015 8:27  1/13/2015 9:27    0.04
3675    1/13/2015 9:27  1/13/2015 10:27   0.04
3678    1/13/2015 11:02 1/13/2015 12:02   0.04
```

CODE:

```
SELECT timeToPost

FROM(
SELECT up.id, userJoinDate, firstPost, round(julianday(firstPost)-julianday(userJoinDate),2) as timeToPost
FROM (SELECT u.id, u.create_date as userJoinDate, min(p.create_date) as firstPost 
FROM Users u
JOIN posts p
ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.create_date > '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY 1
) as up

ORDER BY 4 DESC
) as medianVal

LIMIT 2 - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM medianVal) % 2 -- odd 1, even 2
      OFFSET (SELECT (COUNT(*) - 1) / 2 FROM medianVal)
```

Comment: Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

A table alias is different from a table itself.  It cannot be re-used in a `from` clause.

However, a CTE can do what you want, so just rewrite the logic as:

```
with medianval as (
      select up.id, userJoinDate, firstPost, round(julianday(firstPost)-julianday(userJoinDate),2) as timeToPost
      from (select u.id, u.create_date as userJoinDate, min(p.create_date) as firstPost 
            from Users u join
                 posts p
                 on p.user_id = u.id
            where u.create_date > '2015-01-01'
            group by 1
           ) up
      )
select timeToPost
from medianval
order by timeToPost desc
limit 2 - (select count(*) from medianVal) % 2 -- odd 1, even 2
offset (select (count(*) - 1) / 2 from medianVal)
```

Note:  This only addresses the missing table problem.  I haven't validated the code for other problems or its suitability for calculating a median.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh.... Thank you! I realized after the post that probably I could create a temporary table, but this even better!