# SQLite impute missing values by mean for every group

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I have an SQLite table as shown below.

| students | grades |
| --- | --- |
| Nick | 34 |
| Nick | 42 |
| Nick | 86 |
| Nick | Null |
| John | 38 |
| John | 12 |
| John | 74 |
| John | Null |
| Colin | 87 |
| Colin | 23 |
| Colin | 46 |
| Colin | 42 |

What I want to do is impute Null values with the mean of each student's grades.
For example, missing value for Nick will be 54 and for John 41.3.
How can I do this in SQL code? I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET grades = (
  SELECT ROUND(AVG(t2.grades), 1) 
  FROM tablename AS t2 
  WHERE t2.students = t1.students
)
WHERE t1.grades IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=65411f73e7662a72eb9803f2c0bedca7).

Comment: It works! thank you very much. How about if I want to impute median instead of mean?

Comment: @FikriÇetin there is no built-in function that calculates the median. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763965/how-can-i-calculate-the-median-of-values-in-sqlite to get some idea.